# jmap output understanding

Tags: java, jvm, heap-memory, classloader

Jmap histo live O/P is like this:

```
   8:         72350       99408664  <instanceKlassKlass>
   9:         72350       85348552  <constantPoolKlass>
  10:         70884       48964288  <constantPoolCacheKlass>
```

Can anyone please explain the meaning of in instanceKlassKlass and the other two??

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/340997/constantpoolclass-in-java-heap

Answer (score 0):

These are internal JVM objects used for class loading.

Each class loaded by your JVM is represented inside the VM as an instance of class `Klass`, these objects reside in the Heap. The heap thus contains your application data plus data/objects used by the VM internally.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I got the basic part, can you guide me from where i can read more about it.